Content displayed using Thymeleaf functions not actually showing up in web view
I was learning how to code using java and html. The code using Thymeleaf functions are not actually working in html files.
I think I am well setup and checked as many things that can cause Thymeleaf not to load, but here is my setups and codes.
The file structure:file structure
My pom.xml file:
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


application.properties:
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.time-zone=GMT+8

spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute=req
spring.freemarker.suffix=.html
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates/
spring.freemarker.content-type=text/html
spring.freemarker.enabled=true

spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

The actual .html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>111</h1>
<div th:text="111"></div>
</body>
</html>

And the result:
only the upper one showed up
So this is a pretty staightforword one, it should show 2 lines of "111"s but it only showed the top one. The one using Thymeleaf function does not show up.
I tried rebooting the code and IDEA several times and asking ChatGPT for help. I checked application.properties and pom.xml to see if Thymeleaf is properly loaded and it seems it is. The help menu that shows a large number of "th:" something if you type "th" also showed up as I was making the .html more simple.
It was such a basic problem that no one is silly enough to do that, thus everyone is telling me to check those things, but no one seems to have the same problem as I do. I just do not know.

Despite me thinking it had anything to do with where the th:text was place, I think it's simply that freemarker is doing the processing, which doesn't know what th:text is.  So, remove your freemarker dependency and try this again.

@lane.maxwell Nevermind it worked. I am such an idiot.

@lane.maxwell Thanks a lot. I did not know that freemarker can cause conflict with thymeleaf.
